# jQuery overlapping div wont nullify the hidden onclick of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
jQuery('#warning').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked at warning');
});

jQuery('#content').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked at content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning">
  <div id="content">This is the content</div>
  dsfdfsdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73jykhj0/

unfortunatly clicking at `content` also triggers clicking at `warning` too. How to eliminate clicking at `warning`?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Stopping event propagation is considered a rather bad practice - you might have other functionality on the page, that relies on such events bubbling up. You should rather check what the target of the event was in your handler function, and based on that do something ... or not.

Comment: try get out of function if content is clicked see this https://jsfiddle.net/73jykhj0/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prevent event from bubbling up using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
jQuery('#warning').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked at warning');
});

jQuery('#content').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  console.log('clicked at content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning">
  <div id="content">This is the content</div>
  dsfdfsdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf
</div>
```

---

Or, You can check the target of the event using [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) then do the needful.

```js
jQuery('#warning').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is('#content')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('clicked at warning');
});

jQuery('#content').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked at content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning">
  <div id="content">This is the content</div>
  dsfdfsdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below. Adding `return false` for click on content.

```js
jQuery('#warning').click(function() {
    alert('clicked at warning');
});

jQuery('#content').click(function() {
    alert('clicked at content');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning">
    <div id="content">This is the content</div>
    dsfdfsdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf
</div>
```